# How to force the user to login before using the bot?

Tags: botframework, bot-framework-composer

How to force the user to login before being allowed to see the messages or reply with bots created using Bot Framework Composer?

I used the Oauth prompt card but that only ask to log in once. If the user clicks 'cancel' the bot still works for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first prompt the user for login in the Greeting dialog. You can then save the user token in a variable, so you can check if the token exists at the start of any intent and prompt the user to login if the token does not exist / is not valid.